# SSRS 2005 concat values in dropdown parameter

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a dataset which I want to use as a parameter for my chart in SSRS. The puzzle that I am trying to solve is as below.

My DataSet has 4 columns and in the Dropdown parameter I can only specify label and value. I am not able to specify two columns as Label and two columns as value.

Does anyone know how to concat the values in the dropdown?

I don't want to concat these values in my sql query generating the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=Fields!Col1.Value & " - " & Fields!Col2.Value & " - " &

Make this an expression

If this is not possible, then simply create a calculated field in the dataset which is the concat, then use this as the value.

(to create a calculated field, go to the datasets window CTRL + ALT + D, right click on your dataset 'add calc field').

Comment: Calculated Field seems to be the only option or concat in the sql query itself.